# Asp.net Core API Deploying with a database on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, localdb

I'm trying to deploy an API on IIS. But no matter how I try to do it, I can't solve the following problem.

When I try to deploy asp.net core example api there is no problem with it. When I call an endpoint there are data.
[image]

If I try to deploy my api that uses a database I got an error.

The problem that I got when I try write an endpoint is:

[image]

I think it is a database permission problem.
IIS settings are below

[image]

Connection string is below

"Local": "server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb; database=eahworksafety;user id=eah;Password=eah;Integrated Security=false;"

MSSQL settings are below

[image]

I try to deploy an api locally on IIS webserver. I get an error when I try to reach an endpoint.

Comment: edit connection string to "Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb; Initial Catalog=eahworksafety;User ID =eah; Password =eah;",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you can see more deatiales about this problem by going on your windows, search [Event viewer] ->then enter to the section windows logs->Application and see the problems.

secound, what I noticed that you are trying to connect to the localDb  that exsist in visual studio by default, I have faced the same problem befor so I changed the connection string form the localDB to sql server 2019  that I instulled and worked.

Comment: Yea I noticed after I posted this problem. As you mentioned, I fixed it. Thank you.